# Concatenation of Vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation

I have these 10 vectors in MATLAB, mean(alltmws{l}'), where l is from 1 to 10. The size of each of  these vectors is 1X10001.  Now I want to store all these values in one vector, one after the other, so that I can calculate and plot the overall mean. How can I do this concatenation? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have, for example,

```
a{1} = rand(10,1);
a{2} = rand(10,1);
a{3} = rand(10,1);
```

You can do

```
A = [a{:}];
A = A(:)
```

EDIT:  The question is ambiguous, but if it is the means that one wants to concatenate and plot, you can do:

```
% Create example data
data = {};
for k = 1:10
  data{k} = rand(100,1);
end

% Compute and plot array of means
mu = []
for k = 1:length(data)
  mu(k) = mean(data{k});
end
plot(mu)
```

Comment: Can't I use a for loop? Such that for all l from 1 to 10, the values of mean(alltmws{l}') are stored one after the other? Is Assigning a{1}. a{2} etc, necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `1x10` cell array, then you can directly do:

```
concatnatedArray=cell2mat(yourCellArray);
```

If you have a `10x1` cell array, first transpose it and then apply above technique. This will only work if all the vectors in each cell are of the same length, which the case for you.

Comment: How do I put all my alltmws{l} in a cell array?

Comment: alltmws is already a cell array, since you have put curly brackets. So you just have to write `concatnatedArray=cell2mat(alltmws);`