# matlab concatenating vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm new to MATLAB, and programming in general, and I am having difficulty accomplishing what I am sure is a very, very simple task:

I have a list of vectors v_i for i from 1 to n (n in some number), all of the same size k. I would like to create a vector v that is a "concatenation" (don't know if this is the correct terminology) of these vectors in increasing order: what I mean by this is that the first k entries of v are the k entries of v_1, the k+1 to 2k entries of v are the k entries of v_2 etc. etc. Thus v is a vector of length nk.

How should I create v?

To put this into context, here is function I've began writing (rpeakindex will just a vector, roughq would be the vector v I mentioned before):

```
function roughq = roughq(rpeakindex)
for i from 1 to size(rpeakindex) do
    v_i = [rpeakindex(i)-30:1:rpeakindex(i)+90]
end
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenation of Vectors in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170467/concatenation-of-vectors-in-matlab)

Comment: what do you mean by list of vectors? cell array or 2d matrix?

Comment: @User1551892 well I've began writing a function that defines the vectors v_i

Comment: If your aim is to create one long vector (which is indeed called "concatenation") you could simply write `v = [v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4];` There may be a more convenient way of doing this if the `v_i` are the results of other computations. Can you post some of the code you are working with?

Comment: @User1551892 I'm hoping this vector v will be the output if that makes sense

Comment: @eigenchris sure I'll add that in to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating with `horzcat` is definitely an option, but since these vectors are being created in a function, it would be better to concatenate these vectors automatically in the function itself rather than write out `horzcat(v1,v2,....vn)` manually.

Given the function mentioned in the question, I would suggest something like this:

```
function v = roughq(rpeakindex)
v = zeros(121,length(rpeakindex));                  %// create a 2D array of all zeros
for i = 1:size(rpeakindex) 
    v(:,i) = [rpeakindex(i)-30:1:rpeakindex(i)+90]; %// set result to ith column of v
end
v = v(:)';                                          %'//reshape v to be a single vector with the columns concatenated
end
```

---

Here's a simplified example of what's going on:

```
N = 3;
v = zeros(5,N);
for i = 1:N
    v(:,i) = (1:5)*i;
end
v = v(:)';
```

Output:

```
v =

     1     2     3     4     5     2     4     6     8    10     3     6     9    12    15
```

---

You may want to read up on MATLAB's  [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to understand the `v(:)` syntax.

Comment: this is really close to what I'm looking thanks so much. But I can't quite get it to work as a function. I would like to make a function whose input is the vector rpeakindex and whose output is your vector v. How would I write that?

Comment: @neil See my edited answer. I just added a line to make the code into a function called `roughq` that takes a vector `rpeakindex` as an input and outputs `v`.

Comment: thanks a million. I am encountering one final problem. When I input a vector x into the function roughq and conclude the statement with a semicolon, my output isn't suppressed. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @neil That would be my fault. :P I forgot a semi-colon in the code. It should be fixed in the latest edit.

Comment: @neil You are quite welcome. If you are new to MATLAB I suggest watching [this video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-with-matlab-68985.html) to get familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try two things.

First, for concatenating vectors there are a couple of methods [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85019), but the simplest would be

```
h = horzcat(v_1, v_2);
```

The bigger problem is to enumerate all vectors with a "for" loop. If your `v_n` vectors are in a cell array, and they are in fact `v{i}`, then

```
h= [];
for j=1:n
 h = horzcat(h, v{i});
end
```

Finally, if they only differ by name, then call them with

```
h=[];
for j=1:n
 h= horzcat(h, eval(sprintf('v_%d',j));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the arrays (vectors) be:

```
v_1=1:10;
v_2=11:20;
v_3=21:30;
v_4=31:40;
```

and so on.

If they are few (e. g. 4), you can directly set then as input in the `cat` function:

```
v=cat(2,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)
```

or the `horzcat` function

```
v=horzcat(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)
```

otherwise you can use the `eval` function within a loop

```
v1=[];
for i=1:4
   eval(['v1=[v1 v_' num2str(i) ']'])
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should really use `int2str` in this case. However, if one has to resort to any solution involving `eval` for something like this, there are probably other  parts of the code that need restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 2d matrix, you are using for holding vectors and each row hold vector v then you can simply use the reshape command in matlab like below:

```
V = [] ;    
for i = 1:10
   V(i,:) = randi (10,1 ,10) ;
end     
V_reshpae = reshape (V, 1, numel(V)) ;
```